# undefined reference to `luaL_loadfilex'

Tags: c++, lua

Пытаюсь добавить к проекту Lua, но при компиляции вылезает ошибка:

> LuaScript.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to luaL_loadfilex

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Linaria)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_INIT g++)

find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
find_package(Lua REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    include/
)

file(GLOB SRC
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(Linaria ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(Linaria 
    ${SFML_LIBRARIES} 
    ${LUA_LIBRARIES} 
)

set_target_properties(Linaria PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "Linaria"
    CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1
)

add_definitions(-std=c++11 -w)
```

А вот код:

```
void LuaScript::open(std::string file){
        if(!this->luaState){
            this->luaState = luaL_newstate();

            if(luaL_loadfile(this->luaState, file.c_str())){
               // File not found
            }

            luaL_openlibs(this->luaState);
        }
    }
}
```

Нигде не нашел ничего, что помогло бы решить ошибку.

Что делать?

Comment: `undefined reference` часто говорит о том, что не подключена (линкером) соответствующая библиотека. Может быть версия не та, или разрядность.

Comment: возможно, надо подключать не только `lua`, но и `lualib`.

Comment: добавил в CMakeLists.txt `-llua5.2 -llualib5.2`, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: а у вас установлена эта библиотека liblua (lualib) нужной версии? для справки: чтобы пользователь получил уведомление о комментарии в дискуссии, где больше одного отвечающего, надо явно упомянуть этого пользователя (`@пользователь`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, у меня установлена библиотека lua 5.2

Comment: Спасибо всем! Нужна была строчка  `-llua -llualib`. Вопрос закрыт.